# When did/will Microsoft End Security Updates for Vista

Tags: windows, security, windows-vista

Does anybody know when will Microsoft End Security Updates for Vista (or have they done so already)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for being somewhat rude, but did you even *attempt* to research the subject? It’s literally *one* [Google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=When+did%2Fwill+Microsoft+End+Security+Updates+for+Vista) away.

Comment: Well if you did, that needs to go in the question. It helps people determine what you’re really asking. It also shows you’re not using Super User as a research service, which is very much frowned upon.

Comment: @Daniel B, Yes I did. There is a lot of stuff about the different types of support. I know "Mainstream Support" ended in 2017 and "Extended Support" will end 2020. I specifically want to know about secuity patches (and I suppose which type of support it's covered under), Google didn't tell me that, which is a shame

Comment: Vista mainstream ended in 2012, total end 2017. You're reading the wrong bit, your dates are closer to those for Windows 7, mainstream ended 2015, total end 2020. Basically, these days, if you want to be running a legacy OS, then Win7 is good for a couple of years. Win8 was bad, 8.1 ok, but a bit too much like Win10.

Comment: you can still install the Server 2008 updates on your own, to have an up to date Vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vista support ended completely as of April 2017

From https://support.microsoft.com/help/22882/windows-vista-end-of-support

> Windows Vista support has ended
>
> What is Windows Vista end of support?
>   As of April 11, 2017, Windows
>   Vista customers are no longer receiving new security updates,
>   non-security hotfixes, free or paid assisted support options, or
>   online technical content updates from Microsoft. Microsoft has
>   provided support for Windows Vista for the past 10 years, but the time
>   has come for us, along with our hardware and software partners, to
>   invest our resources towards more recent technologies so that we can
>   continue to deliver great new experiences.
>
> What happens if I continue to use Windows Vista?﻿
>
> If you continue to use Windows Vista now that support has ended, your
>   computer will still work but it might become more vulnerable to
>   security risks and viruses. Internet Explorer 9 is no longer
>   supported, so if your Windows Vista PC is connected to the Internet
>   and you use Internet Explorer 9 to surf the web, you might be exposing
>   your PC to additional threats. Also, as more software and hardware
>   manufacturers continue to optimize for more recent versions of
>   Windows, you can expect to encounter more apps and devices that do not
>   work with Windows Vista.
>
> Microsoft has also stopped providing Microsoft Security Essentials for
>   download on Windows Vista. If you already have Microsoft Security
>   Essentials installed, you'll continue to receive antimalware signature
>   updates for a limited time. However, please note that Microsoft
>   Security Essentials (or any other antivirus software) will have
>   limited effectiveness on PCs that do not have the latest security
>   updates. This means that PCs running Windows Vista will not be secure
>   and will still be at risk for virus and malware.

A full Microsoft Lifecycle Factsheet is at [MS Support - Windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)